# How can I exclude a material from (only) the alpha channel?

Tags: rendering

How can I exclude a material from the render alpha channel, but still show the material in the color channel?

I'm used to a 3DsMax+V-ray workflow, and the obvious solution here would be to add a "wrapper material" to a material to control alpha in the alpha channel.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is using the *Cryptomatte* in the *Compositor*. First you have to enable it in the *View Layer Properties*, under *Passes* > *Cryptomatte* check *Object*.

[image: enable cryptomatte pass]

Now you can render the image (and you don't even have to set the background to *Film* > *Transparent* when using *Cryptomatte*) and go to the *Compositor*. Make sure *Backdrop* is enabled since you need the *Viewer* node.

Now add the node <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Add</kbd> > *Add* > *Matte* > *Cryptomatte* (not *Cryptomatte (Legacy)*!) and plug the *Image* output of the *Render Layers* node into the *Image* input of the *Cryptomatte* node. Plug the *Pick* output into the *Viewer* node.

[image: cryptomatte pick]

If you now click on the *Plus* symbol next to the *Matte ID* field of the *Cryptomatte* you'll get an eyedropper tool with which you can pick an object in the image. Hovering over an object displays its name. If you click on it, it gets added to the *Matte ID* list.

[image: adding matte id]

By the way, this would also work if the *Cryptomatte* node was not plugged into *Viewer*, if you view the original render - you just need the *Viewer* to display something where you can pick from.

Now after you picked the yellow and red cube in this example, their names are in the *Matte ID* list. If you change your mind, you can always choose the *Minus* symbol to pick objects you want to remove from the list or add more with *Plus* (if there were more objects in the scene).

If you now plug the *Image* output of the *Cryptomatte* node you can see the result: the image is masked to only display the picked objects. Not only the blue disappeared, but also the background although it was not set to *Transparent*.

[image: masked image]

But since your goal was to have the blue cube visible but remove it from the *Alpha* channel, you can use the *Matte* output of the node to get a black and white image of the masked result (sorry mine doesn't look white, I have *Filmic* enabled):

[image: matte output]

Comment: Great! Just what I needed! :)