# Is it possible to Render a light pass in eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have a night city animation. This consists of multiple mesh cubes with window image textures. The windows are lit by using an emission in the Principled BSDF.

When rendering in Eevee, is it possible to render only the light in the scene and make all black transparent?

[image]

Comment: Did you try enabling the *Emission* render pass ? It won't give you transparency (as expected for emission passes).

Comment: As @Lutzi says, you can use the _Emission_ pass in the _View Layer Properties_ under _Passes_ > _Light_ > _Other_. Not all light passes work in _EEVEE_, but this one does. And even though it has no transparency, you could still add that emission to a non-transparent background and the black parts will not change anything. For transparency you could also use the _Emission_ pass and plug it into the _Alpha_ input of a _Set Alpha_ node, of course non-white emission will be semi-transparent, but by increasing contrast or maybe just using one color channel by separating them this can be changed.

Comment: But this could have been a good situation where to use the _Cryptomatte_ node. In the _Passes_ you can enable _Cryptomatte_ passes for _Object_, _Material_ and _Asset_. This would only work if those lights were materials on their own, and not just masked parts of a mostly non-emissive material. But yours should work. Therefore I will just link to an answer where I explain the use only in case you are interested: [How can I exclude a material from the Alpha channel?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/288928/how-can-i-exclude-a-material-from-only-the-alpha-channel/288933#288933)

Comment: Lutzi, Gordon - Many thanks! Using the Emission pass & Set Alpha node does exactly what I'm looking for.  The semi-transparent parts give a nice effect. I can use this as a separate overlay when I'm putting this together in the Video Editor - gives me more control over the Brightness and colour tone - Many thanks again!

Comment: Dumb question - how do you mark a question as answered, it's probably staring me straight in the face, but I can't see a 'Tick Complete' box anywhere.

Comment: Well, this is just the comments section, neither @Lutzi wrote a proper answer nor did I. So you cannot mark anything as answered. Maybe Lutzi can write an answer since he commented first...? Or I'll do that tomorrow. But actually you can write your own answers and even accept them after a grace period if nobody else comes up with an answer you would prefer over your own.